# IE8 problem with tbody background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image

and another IE 8 problem:

We have a table like this one:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<thead>    
<tr>
<th>Erwachsene</th>
<th class="center w95">Preis in €<br /></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1 Tag a´ 4 Stunden</td>
<td class="price">50.-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 Tage a´ 4 Stunden</td>
<td class="price">90.-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>     3 Tage a´ 4 Stunden</td>
<td class="price">130.-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4 Tage a´ 4 Stunden</td>
<td class="price">135.-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5 Tage a´ 4 Stunden</td>
<td class="price">140.-</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the header we have a gradient from light to dark blue - it works perfect - also in IE 8. For tbody we have also defined a background image with gradient from dark blue to white.

The tbody background is positioned with "bottom left" with this pice of code:

```
#leftpanel tbody { background: url(../images/bg_tbody.png) no-repeat bottom left; color: #464646; font: 12px Verdana, Arial; }
```

The right thing is that if we have e.g. 10 table rows, the first 3 are white because the gradient from darf blue to width has only a heigh for about 7 rows. In IE8 the browser isn't very interested in setting the background at bottom left, IE8 sets the background image for the first row - and the rest is transparent.

Anybody any

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and there's no pretty work around. The solution that will give you the most consistent results is going to involve putting your table in a div and giving that div the background, positioning it accordingly.